# SVN server for the Mac that's easy to set up?

Tags: svn, macos, svn-server

i have tried VisualSVN server for the PC, and it seems pretty easy to install and use.  The only catch is that my PC with Vista does crash, or can become not so responsive sometimes, so I am thinking of using an SVN server on the Mac instead.

is there one on the Mac that is easy to install and is reliable too?

Comment: Sounds like you've got some issues with your Vista install that you should sort our regardless.  I'd investigate the NVidia motherboard/chipset drivers as the most probably cause if you're having actual system-wide crashes.

Comment: @Soviut thanks for the hint.  I just looked and it is using ATI Radeon HD 2600 XT... is it less problematic than NVidia's card?

Comment: You don't say what protocol you'd like to use and, more importantly, whether or not you need anonymous access. Who's using this repo, and for what?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[macsvnserver](http://macsvnserver.sourceforge.net) claims to be a drop-installable Subversion server for Mac OS X.  Alternatively, you could use a remote Subversion hosting service like [Beanstalk](http://beanstalkapp.com) or [Unfuddle](http://unfuddle.com) to host your repository.

Comment: Can we trust macsvnserver ? 

In the readme, it saids:

* This is a pre-release version for testing. Do not use it on valuable data! *
Is it working correctly ?

Comment: Finally, I use the free plan of Unfuddle, and I it's very good !

Answer (score 0):

If you're using OS X 10.5 Server, you really should consider using the macports SVN. Macports is a single install and the SVN port automatically integrates with the system apache 2.0 including authenticating to OpenDirectory.