# subversioning ipad app project

Tags: iphone, xcode, svn, ipad, version-control

I am currently looking at setting up an Ipad app project into subversion.

Ive had a lot of experience with windows based development and .net. With this we have just created a repository in a network folder (by just right clicking -> TortiseSVN -> create repository) , than all we have done is our developers have checked out from this directory.

How do we go about doing this in xcode. I know subversion is integrated with xcode and I am pretty confident of doing everything (from tutorials) except for the creation of the repository.

Just wondering how we go about creating a repository in a folder based up on network folder?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Google for the svn book.
It should have everything you need to know with the exception of Xcode specifics.

Honestly, you probably don't want to create a repository on someone's development machine, especially if you are giving people network access.

You should setup an actual SVN server or use an online service.

Here is a question posted in 2009: [SVN server for the Mac that's easy to set up?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/900804/281566)

Here is the "official" Ubuntu guide if you chose to run the SVN server on top of Ubuntu (which is my recommendation). Google for "install svn ubuntu".

Sorry I can't post multiple links yet.

Comment: @MistakesRInevitable You really, really don't want to be using a repo off some machine via a network share.  Setup a proper server as suggested in this answer.  And make sure you can backup and restore your repository.

Comment: the repository is to be placed up on a network server. And there is only two developers in this project so it seems overkill to use an svn server

Comment: What do you mean by "network server"? While you can place a repo on a network share, it is not recommended. The Tortoise SVN docs explain this pretty well. http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-repository.html#tsvn-repository-local-share. Setting up an actual server can be as easy as your make it. Since you have a small team, I would most likely host the server on a home network and provide SSH access to your partner. The server could be a virtual machine for added ease in management.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% sure since I mainly use the terminal for svn operations on mac but

if you go in XCode to the scm you can configure the repositories for your project

once that is set  up (I guess you know how to do this form your question), you simply you can go scm->repositories

select the one you want and you can then modify it